# Will android:supportsRtl = false will make my application non-compatible for rtl enable devices

Tags: android, google-play

If We disable android:supportsRtl in our application, will users have rtl enabled devices, be able to download it from play store?

Comment: Yes, we are also facing the same issue in one of our app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl), `android:supportsRtl` has nothing to do with device filtering. It is only used to tell the system if it should try to show your app int RtL mode.